# Is there a standard to HP monitor series and their product naming convention?

Tags: display

For some reason Dell seem to be one of the rare companies with clear published references on this. Note, I'm European and assume this may differ across markets.

I'm finding HP monitors
HP P24 G5
HP E27 G5
HP E24i G4

While it is clear the first letter is the product series, then comes the diagonal size, suffix letter and generation number, I'm yet to find a good reference what is their product series range, and what do suffix letters mean?